# Using TotalOrderPartitioner in Hadoop streaming

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm using python with Hadoop streaming to do a project, and I need the similar functionality provided by the `TotalOrderPartitioner` and  `InputSampler` in Hadoop, that is, I need to sample the data first and create a partition file, then use the partition file to decide which K-V pair will go to which reducer in the mapper. I need to do it in Hadoop 1.0.4.

I could only find some Hadoop streaming examples with `KeyFieldBasedPartitioner` and customized partitioners, which use the `-partitioner` option in the command to tell Hadoop to use these partitioners. The examples I found using `TotalOrderPartitioner` and  `InputSampler` are all in Java, and they need to use the `writePartitionFile()` of `InputSampler` and the `DistributedCache` class to do the job. So I am wondering if it is possible to use `TotalOrderPartitioner` with hadoop streaming? If it is possible, how can I organize my code to use it? If it is not, is it practical to implement the total partitioner in python first and then use it?

Answer (score 0):

Did not try, but taking the example with KeyFieldBasedPartitioner and simply replacing:

-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner

with

-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner

Should work.

Comment: TotalOrderPartitioner need a partition file to work(otherwise it would complaint the file doesn't exist), but I couldn't find a way to specify this file in the command. Also, I want to use the `InputSampler` to generate this partition file, but I couldn't find a way to use it in the command either.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to use TotalOrderPartitioner in Hadoop streaming is to recode a small part of it to get the pathname of its partition file from an environment variable then compile it, define that environment variable on your systems and pass its name to the streaming job with the -cmdenv option (documented at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Streaming_Command_Options.

Source code for TotalOrderPartitioner is available at [TotalOrderPartitioner.java](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/TotalOrderPartitioner.html). In it getPartitionFile() is defined on two lines starting on line 143 and its second line shows that if its not given an argument it uses DEFAULT_PATH as the partition file name.  DEFAULT_PATH is defined on line 54 as "_partition.lst" and line 83 has a comment that says its assumed to be in the DistributedCache. Based on that, without  modifying getPartitionFile(), it should be possible to use _partition.lst as the partition filename as long as its in DistributedCache.

That leaves the issue of running an InputSampler to write content to the partition file. I think that's best done by running an already coded Java MapReduce job that uses TotalOrderPartitioner, at least to get an example of the output of InputSampler to determine its format. If the example job can be altered to process the type of data you want then you could use it to create a partition file usable for your purposes.  A couple of coded MapReduce jobs using TotalOrderPartitioner are [TotalOrderSorting.java](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch4/TotalOrderSorting.java) and [TotalSortMapReduce.java](https://github.com/alexholmes/hadoop-book/blob/master/src/main/java/com/manning/hip/ch4/sort/total/TotalSortMapReduce.java).

Alternatively at [twittomatic](https://github.com/nopper/twittomatic) there is a simple, custom [IntervalPartitioner.java](https://github.com/nopper/twittomatic/blob/master/helpers/hadoop/sorter/IntervalPartitioner.java) in which the partition file pathname is hardcoded as /partitions.lst and in the [sorter](https://github.com/nopper/twittomatic/tree/master/helpers/hadoop/sorter) directory is supplied a script, sample.sh, that builds partition.lst using hadoop, a live twitter feed and sample.py. It should be fairly easy to adapt this system to your needs starting with replacing the twitter feed with a sample of your data.